# JSON not deserializing correctly with large object

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I am trying to deserialize a JSON string and for some reason it will not work.

```
string json_string = "{'CartID':{'ID':253419,'AuthenticatedKey':223239},'CustomerID':null,'PurchaseItems':null,'TenderInformation':null,'ModifyCartItems':null,'AdditionalCartInformation':{'ServiceInformation':{'ServiceInformationItem':[{'ServiceID':243401}]}}}";

modifyCartReq = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ModifyCartReq>(json_string);
```

I have also tried the following

```
string json_string = "{'CartID':{'ID':253419,'AuthenticatedKey':223239},'CustomerID':null,'PurchaseItems':null,'TenderInformation':null,'ModifyCartItems':null,'AdditionalCartInformation':{'ServiceInformation':{'ServiceInformationItem':[{'ServiceID':243401}]}}}";

modifyCartReq = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ModifyCartReq>(json_string);
```

I get the same error below

Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'ExampleType' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
Path 'AdditionalCartInformation.ServiceInformation.ServiceInformationItem', line 1, position 213.

From my attempts at solving this It feels like some syntax issue is ultimately the cause of this.

Comment: Can you share `ModifyCartReq` class?

Comment: This is simply not valid JSON. JSON needs double quotes `"` not single quotes `'`

Answer (score 1):

you have to fix json_string

```
{
    "CartID": {
        "ID": 253419,
        "AuthenticatedKey": 223239
    },
    "CustomerID": null,
    "PurchaseItems": null,
    "TenderInformation": null,
    "ModifyCartItems": null,
    "AdditionalCartInformation": {
        "ServiceInformation": {
            "ServiceInformationItem": [{
                "ServiceID": 243401
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

try this

```
modifyCartReq = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Root>(json_string);
```

and use this classes

```
 public class CartID
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int AuthenticatedKey { get; set; }
    }

    public class ServiceInformationItem
    {
        public int ServiceID { get; set; }
    }

    public class ServiceInformation
    {
        public List<ServiceInformationItem> ServiceInformationItem { get; set; }
    }

    public class AdditionalCartInformation
    {
        public ServiceInformation ServiceInformation { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public CartID CartID { get; set; }
        public object CustomerID { get; set; }
        public object PurchaseItems { get; set; }
        public object TenderInformation { get; set; }
        public object ModifyCartItems { get; set; }
        public AdditionalCartInformation AdditionalCartInformation { get; set; }
    }
```

just replace objects with your real types.